# For loops into List comprehensions

Tags: python, loops

I'd like to print any number that appears more than once. How do I change my **for loops** into **list comprehensions**?

```
from collections import Counter
cnt=Counter()
in1="4 8 0 3 4 2 0 3".split(" ")
for elt in in1:
    cnt[elt]+=1
more_than_one=[]
for value, amount in cnt.items():
    if amount > 1: more_than_one.append(value)
print(*more_than_one)
```

Desirable output: 4 0 3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of counting the values yourself:

```
cnt=Counter()
in1="4 8 0 3 4 2 0 3".split(" ")
for elt in in1:
    cnt[elt]+=1
```

You can simply pass `in1` to [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to do all the counting for you:

```
cnt = Counter(in1)
```

As for turning your code into a list comprehension, you can try this:

```
from collections import Counter

in1="4 8 0 3 4 2 0 3".split()

cnt = Counter(in1)

print([k for k, v in cnt.items() if v > 1])
```

Which Outputs:

```
['4', '0', '3']
```

**Note:** You also don't need to pass `" "` to `split()`, since it defaults to white space.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> text = "4 8 0 3 4 2 0 3"
>>> counts = Counter(text.split())
>>> valid = [k for k in counts if counts[k] > 1]
>>> valid
['4', '0', '3']
```

Comment: @MadPhysicist In python2 it wont create a list in memory while `.items()` will

Comment: Then  use `iteritems`. Downvote removed though. I hadn't noticed that.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I don't wan tto use `iteritems` because I want a solution that's compatible with both at once